# Can't update Kali Linux light

Tags: apt, kali-linux

My kali-linux-light is version 2019.3

```
apt-get update
Err:1 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'http.kali.org'
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'http.kali.org'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I have tried even changing the

`_apt:x:**100**:65534::/noexistent:/usr/sbin/nologin`

to

`_apt:x:**0**:65534::/noexistent:/usr/sbin/nologin`

but doesn't work.

Please help me I have tried for hours, many possible ways, but nothing changed.

thanks

Comment: Have you considered a different Distro of Gnu/Linux? Kali is not for beginners.

Comment: What change you made. You did not say where, but this looks like it may be `/etc/passwd`. Why change that?

Comment: Are you connected to the internet?

Answer (score 1):

It says in the error message `Temporary failure resolving 'http.kali.org'`. It can not find the name `http.kali.org`, when it does a DNS look up.

Answer (score 0):

Did u try reconnecting to the internet?

This error mostly occurs due to no internet connection.

Always perform a ping `ping www.google.com`(can perform on any site) before trying to update anything

Make sure ur wireless adapter is enabled and selected in the virtual box settings

Answer (score 0):

Try `service dbus restart`; it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

1. Just check your network in without virtual machine
2. Check your network setting then do bridge and do replace tick
3. Do shutdown kali then do restart

Its all bcoz of network is not attaching in kali
Dont worry above steps will help