# Temporary failure in name resolution, only in apt

Tags: networking, android, chroot

I'm using Kali nethunter on my A12 phone. Network is supposed to work out of the box.
`apt update` gives:

```
Ign:1 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling InRelease
Ign:1 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling InRelease
Err:1 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling InRelease
Temporary failure resolving 'http.kali.org'
```

However:

1. `ping 8.8.8.8` works
2. `ping http.kali.org` works
3. `dig http.kali.org` works

All of them as `kali`, `root` and `_apt` users.
`/etc/resolv.conf` has DNS entries and is readable by everyone.

As it is chroot, systemctl won't do.

Any idea?

Comment: Relating https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/553740/117549 as it has a similar issue.

Comment: Yes, I tried restarting dbus to no avail